# Alt+drag no longer creates links?

Tags: shortcut-keys, symbolic-link, plasma, dolphin

It's been driving me mad: it used to be in KDE/Plasma that if you alt+drag a file and dropped it then it would create a soft-link. But that has stopped working, and I can't work out how to do it: copying and then right-click doesn't given an option in the menu either. So, how?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you now have to use **meta+drag** (ie win-key, or "windows key", with drag), which raises the menu - in dolphin on KDE, for me running Kubuntu 19.04 - which offers the choices of making a plain copy or creating a link/soft-link/symbolic-link.

For some **ctrl+shift+drag** may work too, that's what the little pop-up menu suggests but it's not working for me somehow (which might be a bug).

Hope that helps someone because it took me an hour and I couldn't find the right words to get the search engines to return anything useful!